# Кастование числа к строке не кидает ClassCastExeption при использовании дженериков - почему?

Tags: java, generics, методы

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в строчке `//(?!)` не выбрасывается исключение ClassCastExeption? Там стоит `(T)`, где T=String, а значит там `(String) new Integer(42)`, что должно давать исключение... JVM должна привести тип, но почему-то она этого не делает. Дальше мы смотрим тип `t` и видим `Integer`, что действительно является реальным типом `t`. Но факт того, что мы вывели тип, показывает: исключение не создалось. Потом программа выбрасывает исключение там, где была вызвана функция `A.<String>f()`.

***Кстати!*** Помнится мне, Bruce Eckel учит тому, что существует некоторый декомпилятор javap, он сам пишет код программы то ли из байт-кода, то ли из .class... Не изучал. Если кто сведущ в этом, попробуйте заставить декомпилятор построить этот кусок кода, может он покажет, что там происходит на самом деле, и почему?

```
public class A {
    public static <T> T f() {
        T t = (T) new Integer(42); // (?!) ЧТО ЧЁРТ ВОЗЬМИ ЗДЕСЬ ВООБЩЕ ПРОИСХОДИТ?!
        System.out.println(t.getClass());
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.<String>f()); // как здесь возможно исключение? ахаха, вы серьёзно?
    }
}
```

**Новое:**
Итак, друзья. Самым частым ответом стало: метод `f()` -- это обычный метод, который компильнулся как обычный, но с учётом того, что результаты его вызовов приводятся к типу, передаваемому как `<NameOfTheClass>`. Вроде бы уже всё хорошо, и можно принять такой ответ, но если бы оно правда так работало в Java... Дело в том, что можно в `main(String[])` попытаться вызвать кое что ещё более взрывное:

```
System.out.println(A.<Double>f());
```

Удивительно, но в консоли выйдет:

```
//output:
class java.lang.Integer
42
```

Так вот если у нас невидимо это выглядит так:

```
System.out.println((Double)A.<Double>f());
```

То попробуйте это компильнуть -- выйдет ошибка ахахахха, от куда вывод, что всё таки работает оно не так...

Мои догадки на этот счёт таковы, что метод `println()` перегружен, и в случае `A.<String>f()` он выбирал версию `println(String arg)`, а в случае `A.<Double>f()` он понимал, что `Double` версии нет и ставил `println(Object arg)` из-за чего, для нашего `(Object)Integer(42)` вызывалось `.toString()` и выводилось 42.

Для меня здесь странно то, что почему-то в первом случае, когда мы вызывали `A.<String>f()` он, как многие здесь считают вызывал это так `(String)A.<String>f()`, от куда ставил версию `println(String arg)`, а во второй раз, при вызове `A.<Double>f()` он не попытался сделать так `(Double)A.<Double>f()`, он сразу выбрал `println(Object arg)`...

Хотите сказать, что вся технология такая умная, что если возврат параметризованной/обобщённой функции проверяется на существование как аргумент в перегруженном методе `println()` с успехом, то приведение не вызывается [например `String` версия `println()` существует, ага, приведём выходной `Object` от `A.f()` к указанному `String`],  а если перегруженной версии с указанным в типе-параметре для `A.f()` классом версии `println()` нет, то он (компилятор) оставляет версию `println(Object)` и решает не пытаться даже сделать `(Object)(Double)A.<Double>f()`, где сам результат `f()` есть `Object` ?

***Итого:*** Я хочу объяснения принципа работы параметризованных методов (классов), такое объяснение, чтобы был точно понятен алгоритм действий компилятора для создаваемого кода. Если какие-то мои догадки на счёт действий компилятора верны, то я хочу их (моих догадок) подтверждения и очень желательно (!) с ссылкой на какие-нибудь документационные файлы!

Comment: Наверняка вы столкнулись с type erasure, родовой травмой генериков в Java. Сочувствую.

Comment: @VladD, вот бы ещё подробностей немного)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: Я думаю, лучше пусть ответ на этот вопрос напишут джависты, а то я со всеми кознями type erasure не знаком, каюсь.

Comment: @VladD, я вот [второй джавист](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) на сайте, но ответа не знаю)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: Ну, при компиляции `T` заменяется по идее на `Object`, раз нету констрейнтов. И ещё один каст добавляется «на выходе» из метода.

Comment: T != String. Вот если бы вы попробовали использовать возвращаемый результат как String, вы бы получили то самое исключение.

Comment: Если предположить, что компилятор дополняет `A.<String>f()` до `(String)A.<String>f()`, то почему он отказывается сделать это здесь: `Object t = new Integer(42);` --> `String t = (String) new Integer(42)`, и выдать таки исключение? .......

Comment: Потому что тип возвращаемого значения из метода должен быть строго определен, а внутри метода ваш переданный `String` всё равно стирается в `Object`

Comment: iksuy, если Вам не сложно, найдите документацию, подтверждающую, что всё это действительно ТАК работает, и разместите это как ответ, пожалуйста! Ибо иначе можно думать, что угодно, я любым способом объяснять себе как это так произошло. Я очень хочу основательно понять суть происходящего, чтобы последующее изучение материала было проще!

Comment: @Direct еще раз, он не дополняет

Comment: @Direct вот вам [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html), [еще немного документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7) и книга [*Java Generics and Collections:  Speed Up the Java Development Process / by Naftalin & Wadler*](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0596527756/)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNyQYTp-Njw вот крутой доклад по теме, кстати, прям рекомендую

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это байткод `main` при вызове `A.<Double>f()`

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #4    // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: invokestatic  #7    // Method f:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       6: invokevirtual #6    // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       9: return
```

А это байткод `main` при вызове `A<String>.f()`

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #4      // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: invokestatic  #7      // Method f:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       6: checkcast     #8      // class java/lang/String
       9: invokevirtual #9      // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      12: return
```

Обратите внимание на строку `invokevirtual`, в первом случае вызывается метод с сигнатурой `println(Object o)`, во втором - `println(String s)`
В случае с `Double` после стирания типов метод `f()` возвращает `Object`, метода `println` для `Double` нету (да, можно анбоксить `Double` и вызвать `println` для примитива `double`, но приоритет отдаётся выбору подходящего метода), поэтому выбирается метод для `Object`, внутри спокойно вызывается `String.valueOf` и всё хорошо.
В случае со `String` есть метод `println` для `String` и компилятор решает, что нужно вызывать именно его, поэтому там есть каст.

Я обернул `System.out.println` в свой `println` для 3 типов:

```
static void println(Double d){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(d));
}

static void println(String s){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(s));
}

static void println(Object o){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(o));
}
```

И теперь вы уже догадались что будет при вызове?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    println(Main.<Double>f()); 
}
```

Компилятор увидит, что есть перегруженный `println` для `Double` и поставит каст (и тут как раз ошибка будет):

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #7     // Method f:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       3: checkcast     #8     // class java/lang/Double
       6: invokestatic  #9     // Method println:(Ljava/lang/Double;)V
       9: return
```

Comment: _"анбоксить Double"_ - нет, `Double` - это не анбоксинг, а просто приведение типа - он по-прежнему ссылочный. Для анбоксинга нужно `double`, а не `Double`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так я и говорю, есть метод `System.out.println(double d)`, я написал про анбоксинг предвкушая вопрос "почему бы компилятору, видя что мы хотим вернуть Double просто не заанбоксить его и вызвать метод для `double`.

Comment: А, понял мысль.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, золотой человек!!! Прямо всё в голове на место встало! Благодарить вроде на этом сайте не принято, только по делу, но твой ответ прямо дал мне многое! Думаю многим, кто будет искать ответы на аналогичные вопросы, твой ответ с примерами даст понять: как, по-хорошему, устроена компиляция чего-то с участием проклятых `<>` ;)

Answer (score 14):

Типов у генериков не существует в рантайме. Это просто проверки при компиляции.

> ```
> public static <T> T f() {
> ```

```
public static Object f() {
```

> ```
> T t = (T) new Integer(42); // (?!) ЧТО ЧЁРТ ВОЗЬМИ ЗДЕСЬ ВООБЩЕ ПРОИСХОДИТ?!
> ```

```
Object t = (Object) new Integer(42); // всё хорошо
```

> ```
> return t;
> ```

По-прежнему всё хорошо. Object.

> ```
> System.out.println(A.<String>f()); // как здесь возможно исключение? ахаха, вы серьёзно?
> ```

```
System.out.println((String)f());
```

Упс.. Там не String. Вот и исключение.

---

Получается такая штука:

```
(String) (Object) new Integer(42);
         ^^^^^^^^------------------ Integer - наследник Object
^^^^^^^^--------------------------- String - наследник Object
```

Ошибки при компиляции нет, а при выполнении первое преобразование оказывается в `f` и оно валидно, а вот второе - уже в `main`, где оно и валится.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы натолкнули меня на новые мысли, почитайте новый вопрос!

Comment: @Direct на этом сайте не принято задавать несколько вопросов под видом одного

Comment: @Direct, вероятно, компилятор выкидывает `/*BEGIN: этот кусок*/(Object)(String)/*END*/(Object)new Integer(42)`, потому что он является неявным преобразованием. А вот явное выкидывать не имеет права.

Comment: @Direct, тут рядом ответ с байт-кодом. Вот строчка проверки приведения: `6: checkcast     #8  // class java/lang/String`. Вероятно, в версии с приведением к Object её нет, либо там Object вместо Double.

Answer (score 7):

Если что то непонятно, всегда можно посмотреть `bytecode`:

```
public class ru.izebit.A {
  public ru.izebit.A();
     Code:
      0: aload_0
      1: invokespecial  #1  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      4: return

  public static <T> T f();
     Code:
      0: new            #2  // class java/lang/Integer
      3: dup
      4: bipush  42
      6: invokespecial  #3 // Method java/lang/Integer."<init>":(I)V
      9: astore_0
      10: getstatic     #4 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      13: aload_0
      14: invokevirtual #5 // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
      17: invokevirtual #6 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      20: aload_0
      21: areturn

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
       0: getstatic     #4  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: invokestatic  #7  // Method f:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       6: checkcast     #8  // class java/lang/String
       9: invokevirtual #9  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       12: return
}
```

Из кода видно, что в методе `f()` не происходит кастования к `String`(судя по всему тип ссылки к которой присваивается новый объект будет Object). Но в момент возвращения этого объекта из параметризированного метода и происходит тот самый каст из за чего и возникает исключение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поправьте (сюдя по всему... -> судя* по всему). Так же: Я бы принял Ваш ответ, если бы он мне как-то помог, но я ничего не понимаю в байт коде (конечно понимаю, но только основное, по аналогии видя оригинальный код). Сделайте какие-нибудь комментарии, выделите места, где видны все эти жонглирования типами? Я очень прошу!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы натолкнули меня на новые мысли, почитайте новый вопрос!

Comment: ну собственно тут особо не нужно разбираться в байткоде, по комментариям справа вполне понятно что происходит. в 6 строке метода f вызывается конструктор Integer, в 14-17 вызывается на данном объекте getClass а потом  происходит вывод в консоль. далее он возвращается из метода и в методе main в 6 строке выполняется инструкция по приведению типа, где и возникает исключение.

Answer (score 6):

Дженериком может быть только не примитивный тип, т.е. супер тип самого простого дженерика - `Object`. Таким образом

```
//позволяет любые непримитивы
public class MyClass<T> {
    T t;

    public MyClass(T tArg) {
       t = tArg;
    }
}
```

вышеприведённый класс будет допускать внутри себя только вызывать у переменной `t` только методы класса `Object`. Т.е. переменная `t` для всего кода в классе `MyClass` будет иметь тип `Object`. Это и объясняет отсутствие `ClassCastException` при приведении числа к объекту.

А вот если более точно указать тип дженерика, то ошибку компиляции мы получим (и не сможет дойти до ошибки времени исполнения):

```
//можно использовать только String или его предков
public class MyClass<? super String> {
    T t;

    public MyClass(T tArg) {
       t = new Integer(42); //ОШИБКА компиляции - переменной t можно присваивать String или Object
    }
}
```

или так, что, правда, бессмысленно, т.к. `String` - финальный класс (т.е. "стерильный" - расширять его нельзя и потомков у него быть не может)

```
//можно использовать только String и его потомков
public class MyClass<T extends String> {
    T t;

    public MyClass(T tArg) {
       t = new Integer(42); //ОШИБКА компиляции - переменной t можно присваивать String или его наследников
    }
}
```

---

Правильная работа вывода типа объясняется иначе:

```
public static <T> T f() {
    T t = (T) new Integer(42); //Всё ОК, т.к. внутри метода T - всегда Object
    System.out.println(t.getClass()); //выведет конкретный тип (String, Integer etc)
}
```

методы в `Java` виртуальны. Т.е. будет вызван не метод класса `T` (т.е. `Object` в рамках метода), а метод конкретной реализации класса `Object` которая находится в памяти. А это уже `String`, `Integer` etc.

---

Итоговая ошибка времени исполнения, видимо, аналогична примеру из [доки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) и код можно аналогично переписать так:

```
 System.out.println((String) A.<String>f());
```

Т.е. вы, указав что метод должен вернуть строку вызываете метод `System.out.println(String arg)`, передавая в него ссылку типа `Object`, коя на самом деле хранит объект типа `Integer`. И вот в момент приведения конкретного числа, хранящегося в памяти к строке и возникает исключение

Comment: Юрий, спасибо! Но до конца понимания дела меня терзает лишь один вопрос: Да, круто что можно представить `A.<String>f()` как `(String)A.<String>f()`, но значит, компилятор понял, что `T` которое возвращает функция есть `String` и сделал своё дело, приведя возврат функции к `T` (т.е. к `String`) но сразу возникает другой вопрос, который мне покоя и не даёт: почему, если компилятор понял к чему нужно привести выход функции, он не сделал того же внутри? как раз таки в роковом месте: `T t = (T) new Integer(42);` ??? Я правда недопонимаю!

Comment: @Direct, всё потому, что компилятор только один раз компилирует каждый метод. Чтобы на этапе компиляции именно в этой ситуации распознать, что в данном конкретном случае имеет место быть несовпадение типов пришлось бы компилировать каждый метод с дженериками столько раз, сколько раз он вызывается. Чтобы этого не делать (это ж время компиляции на порядок возрастёт) метод компилируется единожды и тип подставляется вместо Т только тот, который указан в описании метода. А из описания метода видно лишь, что тип метода - `Object`. Вот и компилируется метод с заменой `T` на `Object`

Comment: Если б было так: `public static <T extends String> T f()` - то ваш код бы не скомпилировался, т.к. компилятор знал бы, что параметр - строка. Но, в данном случае это бессмысленно было бы, ибо строка - финальный класс и такая сигнатура метода тождественна написанию `public static String f()`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы натолкнули меня на новые мысли, почитайте новый вопрос!