# generic-типы (java)

Tags: java, generics

Здравствуйте! Читаю о generic-ах, в качестве примера приводится класс `Optional`

```
package chapt03;

public class Optional <T> {
    private T value;

    public Optional() {
    }

    public Optional(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    } 

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    } 

    public void setValue(T val) {
        value = val;
    } 

    public String toString() {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        return value.getClass().getName() + " " + value; 
    }
}
```

Далее в методе `main` встречается такой фрагмент кода:

```
//параметризация по умолчанию - Object
Optional ob3 = new Optional();
System.out.println(ob3.getValue());
```

Далее момент, который никак не могу понять и прошу помочь в нем разобраться.  Цитата:

> "Объявление generic-типа в виде `<T>`, несмотря на возможность
>   использовать любой тип в качестве параметра, ограничивает область
>   применения разрабатываемого класса. Переменные такого типа могут
>   вызывать только методы класса `Object`. Доступ к другим методам
>   ограничивает компилятор, предупреждая возможные варианты возникновения
>   ошибок".

Но в `main` `ob3` вызывает метод класса `Optional`, который не является методом `Object`. Что я не так понимаю?

Comment: Укажите название книги и автора, если не затруднит.

Comment: Блинов "Java Промышленное программирование"

Comment: Просто в строке *Object Optional ob3 = new Optional();* явно опечатка

Comment: Моя вина. Object - часть предыдущего комментария

Comment: Тогда все в порядке, смотрите ответ Qwertiy

Comment: @Nofate, что-то последнее время полно вопросов по джавовым генерикам...

Comment: @Qwertiy сам в шоке. вчера только на два подряд ответил.

Comment: @MartyMcFly, вот ещё вопрос по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/721089/178988

Comment: Большое всем спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Речь об использовании внутри generic-класса.

```
public void setValue(T val) {
    value = val;
    // Вот тут на value можно вызывать только методы Object'а
    // Нельзя написать `value.length`, например, рассчитывая на то,
    // что кто-то сделает new Optional<String>
}
```

А тип самого класса `Optional` известен и его методы можно вызывать нормально. Так же, как и методы, связанные с генерик-типом там, где он устанавливается:

```
(new Optional<String>("abc")).getValue().length
```

Comment: огромное спасибо! Очень долго мучился с этим вопросом.